# Complete list of US Public and Private Companies by Sector

Tags: historical-data, online-data-source

Where is the best place to go for a free public data set of all US private and public US companies by industry or sector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screener at FINVIZ.com will list all publicly traded US companies with their sector as well as sector specialty.

Comment: I am looking specifically for the architecture industry. Do you know a site that focuses specifically on that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of anything that drills down that far nor do I think that there would be many in that sub sector.  It's a bit or work but you could collect a list of major US architecture firms and then use a symbol look up in Yahoo Finance or other.  It's not likely to be comprehensive but it might produce something.